# Adding an item to a list from another list in python

Tags: python, list

I need to be able to add an item into list a from list b. The item from list b is to be added as soon as `'  '` which is a double space is identified.

Therefore if the first item in the list is not a double space, then the loop goes on to check the next item in the list, if its also not a double space, it carries on until if finds the double space and then it replaces the first available double space with the item from list `b`. This should be looped so that if I run the function again, an item in list `b` is popped and added to the next available double space in list `a`.

```
a = ['a','c','e','j','h','  ','  ','  ','  ']
b = ['b','d','f','i','g']

x = 4
for item in a:
    if item == a[4]:
        break
if a[x] != '  ':
    a[x+1] = b.pop(-2)

else:
    a[x] = a[x+1]

print("list a: ",a)
print("List b: ",b)
```

Output:

```
list a:  ['a', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'h', 'i', '  ', '  ', '  ']
List b:  ['b', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

That works, but I have a feeling my code doesn't work on all inputs. Does it? If it doesn't, what's wrong?

Comment: So it works or not? `x=4` is `i` and `i` really `moved` from b to the first available place in `list a`

Comment: @OfirBaruch; i was kinda cheating to get it to work but i think x should be = 0 to enable it to start checking from the first item in list a. but i could not get it to work with x=0.

Comment: so am i understanding this correctly?  you need to replace each double space in a with an element from b, in order?

Comment: @asia1281; thats right, but only an item at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def move_item(a, b):
    a[a.index('  ')] = b.pop()

>>> a = ['a','c','e','j','h','  ','  ','  ','  ']
>>> b = ['b','d','f','i','g']
>>> move_item(a, b)
>>> print('list a: ', a, '\nlist b: ', b)
list a:  ['a', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'h', 'g', '  ', '  ', '  ']
list b:  ['b', 'd', 'f', 'i']
>>> move_item(a, b)
>>> print('list a: ', a, '\nlist b: ', b)
list a:  ['a', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'h', 'g', 'i', '  ', '  ']
list b:  ['b', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: but i only need one item at a time from list b. how could i edit your code to achieve this.

Comment: @Lycon - I've edited my answer to make it easier to do this one item at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
a = [b.pop() if item == '  ' else item for item in a]
```

gets you:

```
['a', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'h', 'g', 'i', 'f', 'd']
```

Take a look at [Python list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask a question, but here are some hints:

`list.index`, `list.pop`, `a[index_of_doublespace] = popped_value_from_b`

Answer (score 0):

Since this homework, I'm just going to give you some hints:

1. You'll need to work with `a` indexes:

   ```
   for i in range(len(a)):
       if a[i] == ??? :
           a[i] = ??
   ```
2. Why are you popping the `-2`th element? Check out what [`pop`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) does.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this:

`[x.split(' ')[0] or b.pop() for x in a]`